# Stuck on Recursive Division Maze

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, recursion

I've been trying to build a recursive division maze. How it works is it takes a 2d array of '.' and changes to '#' whenever there's a wall. I've gotten to a point in the loop to where it prints out the walls but it doesn't exactly look maze like. Another problem is that its supposed to divide randomly but it kept dividing way to low or high so I ended up just splitting it in half. I've been struggling to figure out how to make it look proper and was wondering if anyone knew how I could clean it up.

```
const grider = (row, col) => {
    let grid = [];
    for (let r = 0; r < row; r++){
        let arr = [];
        for (let c = 0; c < col; c++){
            arr.push('.');
        }
        grid.push(arr);
    }
    return grid;
};

let gridi = grider(25, 25);

const anotherDiv = (grid) => {
    let arr = [];
    console.log(grid[0].length);

    for (let i = 0; i < grid[0].length; i++){

        grid[0][i] = '#';
        arr.push('(' + 0 + ',' + i + ')');
        grid[grid.length - 1][i] = "#";
        arr.push('(' + (grid.length - 1) + ',' + i + ')');
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
       grid[i][0] = '#';
       arr.push('(' + i + ',' + 0 + ')');
       grid[i][grid[0].length - 1] = "#";
       arr.push('(' + i + ',' + (grid[0].length - 1) + ')');
    }

    let gridSize = [];
    let r = grid.length - 1;
    let c = grid[0].length - 1;
    gridSize.push([1, grid.length, 1, grid[0].length])
    console.log(gridSize);
    anotherRecursion(grid, gridSize);

};

anotherDiv(gridi);
function gethole(min, max) {return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);}
function getRandom(min, max) {return Math.floor(((max - min)/2) + min);}


function anotherRecursion(grid, gridSize){

    
    let colSplit = getRandom(gridSize[0][0], gridSize[0][1]);
    let rowSplit = getRandom(gridSize[0][2], gridSize[0][3]);
    let colHole = gethole(gridSize[0][0], gridSize[0][1]);
    let rowHole = gethole(gridSize[0][2], gridSize[0][3]);
    console.log('rowSplit: ' + rowSplit);
    console.log('colSplit: ' + colSplit);
    console.log('rowHole: ' + rowHole);
    console.log('colHole: ' + colHole);

    for (let i = gridSize[0][0]; i < gridSize[0][1]; i++){
        if (rowHole !== i)
            grid[i][rowSplit] = '#';
    }
    for (let i = gridSize[0][2]; i < gridSize[0][3]; i++){
        if (colHole !== i)
            grid[colSplit][i] = '#';
    }

    gridSize.push([gridSize[0][0], colSplit, 
        gridSize[0][2], rowSplit]);
    gridSize.push([gridSize[0][0], colSplit, 
        rowSplit, gridSize[0][3]]);
    gridSize.push([colSplit, gridSize[0][1],
        gridSize[0][2], rowSplit]);
    gridSize.push([colSplit, gridSize[0][1],
        rowSplit, gridSize[0][3]]);
    gridSize.shift();

    // let i = gridSize[gridSize.length - 1][2];
    // do{
    //     grid[colSplit][i] = '#';
    //     i++;
    // }
    // while (grid[colSplit][i] !== '#');

    // let j = gridSize[gridSize.length - 1][0];
    // do{
    //     grid[j][rowSplit] = '#';
    //     j++;
    // }
    // while (grid[j][rowSplit] !== '#');

    console.log(grid);
    console.log((gridSize[1][1] - gridSize[1][0]));
    if ((gridSize[1][1] - gridSize[1][0]) > 2)
        anotherRecursion(grid, gridSize);

}
```

I've just been trying to divide the grid into 4 and divide each segment into 4 and so on. I think my problem is from where I placed the holes and I'm not sure how to end the recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have thought of an algorithm to create a maze yourself. This algorithm will not produce a maze.

The main idea it has, is to divide a rectangular area with both a horizontal and vertical wall, so to get 4 smaller rectangular areas, and to make one hole in the horizontal wall, and one hole in the vertical wall. But this leaves at least one of the four smaller areas completely unreachable.

For example, let's start with this grid (after calling `anotherDiv`):

```
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
# . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . #
# . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . #
# . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . #
# . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . #
# . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . #
# . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . #
# . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . #
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
```

Then apply one division with `anotherRecursion` (excluding the recursive call of it). This could give:

```
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
# . . . . . . . . # . . . . . . . . . #
# . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . #
# . . . . . . . . # . . . . . . . . . #
# # # # # # . # # # # # # # # # # # # #
# . . . . . . . . # . . . . . . . . . #
# . . . . . . . . # . . . . . . . . . #
# . . . . . . . . # . . . . . . . . . #
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
```

There are now two holes, but this leaves the bottom-right area unreachable. So this is already a basic shortcoming of this algorithm. You actually need to place **three** holes to make the hole grid accessible. Moreover, the holes could happen to be placed at the crossing, which makes things worse:

```
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
# . . . . . . . . # . . . . . . . . . #
# . . . . . . . . # . . . . . . . . . #
# . . . . . . . . # . . . . . . . . . #
# # # # # # . # # . # # # # # # # # # #
# . . . . . . . . # . . . . . . . . . #
# . . . . . . . . # . . . . . . . . . #
# . . . . . . . . # . . . . . . . . . #
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
```

The two holes could even be the same hole... which also makes it worse.

Then when you recurse, (starting from the first divisions), you could get this division in the top-left box:

```
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
# . . . . . . . . # . . . . . . . . . #
# # # . # # # # # . . . . . . . . . . #
# . . . . # . . . # . . . . . . . . . #
# # # # # # . # # # # # # # # # # # # #
# . . . . . . . . # . . . . . . . . . #
# . . . . . . . . # . . . . . . . . . #
# . . . . . . . . # . . . . . . . . . #
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
```

Note how this has blocked a hole at its right wall.

Another problem is that you will get to a small area that has an even number of rows or columns on the *inside* of it, so that you cannot divide it further:

```
# # # #
# . . #
# . . #
# # # #
```

There is nothing you can do here. Yet, in a nice maze you'd want to have paths that are "one dot" wide, not two.

In conclusion, this algorithm is not going to work. I'd advise to implement an algorithm that has been proved to work. There are a few explained on [Wikipedia - Maze generation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm), including a depth-first search algorithm, randomized Kruskal's algorithm, randomized Prim's algorithm, Wilson's algorithm, ...etc.

### Solution

The one that comes closest to your attempt is what Wikipedia calls the [recursive division method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm#Recursive_division_method), but you have to make sure:

- The walls are only placed at *even* indices, and the holes at *odd* indices.
- One wall is placed at a time, with one hole in it, and recursion taking care of the two (not four) partitions that are created.

Here is an interactive implementation where you can choose the dimension of the grid:

```js
const toString = (grid) => grid.map(row => row.join(" ")).join("\n");
const randInt = (end) => Math.floor(Math.random() * end);

function fillRow(grid, row, left, right) {
    while (left <= right) grid[row][left++] = "#";
}

function fillCol(grid, col, top, bottom) {
    while (top <= bottom) grid[top++][col] = "#";
}

function divide(grid, top, bottom, left, right) {
    // Check base case: if just one corridor, then there's nothing to divide
    if (bottom - top <= 2 || right - left <= 2) return; 
    // Make the probability equal for all possible dividing-wall positions 
    //    irrespective of their direction.
    // A wall is always at an even index, not 0
    const choice = randInt((bottom - top + right - left) / 2 - 2) * 2 + 2; 
    if (choice >= bottom - top) { // The wall will be vertical
        const splitCol = choice - (bottom - top) + left + 2;
        fillCol(grid, splitCol, top, bottom);
        // Create a hole (always at an odd index):
        grid[randInt((bottom - top) / 2) * 2 + 1 + top][splitCol] = ".";
        // Recur on the two created areas
        divide(grid, top, bottom, left, splitCol);
        divide(grid, top, bottom, splitCol, right);
    } else { // The wall will be horizontal
        const splitRow = choice + top;
        fillRow(grid, splitRow, left, right);
        // Create a hole (always at an odd index):
        grid[splitRow][randInt((right - left) / 2) * 2 + 1 + left] = ".";
        // Recur on the two created areas
        divide(grid, top, splitRow, left, right);
        divide(grid, splitRow, bottom, left, right);
    }
}    

function createGrid(numRows, numCols) {
    if ((numRows - 2) % 2 != 1 || (numCols - 2) % 2 != 1) {
        throw "Grid dimensions should be odd and greater than 1"; 
    }
    // Create grid with no walls
    const grid = Array.from({length: numRows}, () => Array(numCols).fill("."));
    // Build surrounding walls
    fillRow(grid, 0, 0, numCols - 1);
    fillRow(grid, numRows - 1, 0, numCols - 1);
    fillCol(grid, 0, 0, numRows - 1);
    fillCol(grid, numCols - 1, 0, numRows - 1);
    // Main algorithm
    divide(grid, 0, numRows - 1, 0, numCols - 1);
    return grid;
}

// I/O handing
const [input, output] = document.querySelectorAll("input, pre");
input.oninput = refresh;

function refresh() {
    const size = input.valueAsNumber;
    try {
        const grid = createGrid(size, size);
        output.textContent = toString(grid);
    } catch (e) {
        output.textContent = e.message ?? e;
    }
}
refresh();
```

```css
input { width: 4em }
```

```html
Size: <input type="number" min="3" step="2" value="13">
<pre></pre>
```